# How do I set up OAuth1 for authentication in my Quip Live App?

Tags: liveapps, quip

The documentation [here](https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation#auth) only mentions URL and OAuth2 as authentication options. Is there any way for me to set up authentication if my server uses OAuth1?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer on the Live Apps team at Quip. We're working on support for OAuth1, but for now unfortunately there's no way to hook it up through our API. Sorry about that!